# How to get an Identity column value (not committed yet) inside a transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, identity

Inside a TSQL transaction I have an operation of inserting a record into a `MyTable1` and an operation of updating a `MyTable2` with a value of `Identity` column of the `MyTable1` record, which is only to be inserted after the transaction is commited.
 **So, how to get this autogenerated value before it is actually inserted into the table?**

Code just to illustrate the question:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable1(
MyTable1Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
Field1 varchar(50)
) 

CREATE TABLE MyTable2(
MyTable2Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
MyTable1Id int
)


CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(
   @MyVal1  [varchar](50)
)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
-- try to insert
INSERT INTO MyTable1(
   Field1
)
SELECT @MyVal1

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRAN
END

-- update MyTable2
DECLARE @TheUnknownIdValue int
UPDATE MyTable2
SET    MyTable1Id = @TheUnknownIdValue -- how to get the value needed here?
WHERE ...

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRAN
END

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: As long as it's not inserted yet - it's not defined yet. Period. The value of an `IDENTITY` column is **only defined UPON INSERT**.

Comment: @marc_s So, for the code I provided in my question (as long as we are inside transaction) it is just impossible to update with such a value?

Comment: No - after the `INSERT INTO MyTable1`, you can get the last inserted identity for `Table1` using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - is that what you're looking for? The row has to be **inserted** into the table - but doesn't have to be committed yet.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, Marc. Yes, I need the Id value only if the whole transaction is commited. If it is rolled back, everything should stay as before and in this case I don't care about the identity value which were to be used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` **just after** the `INSERT`

```
--
DECLARE @newId INT 
INSERT INTO MyTable1(
   Field1
)
SELECT @MyVal1
--End of Insert here
SELECT @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
--Rest of the procedure
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are inserting one record at a time you can use the scope_identity() function:

```
set @TheUnknownIdValue = scope_identity()
```

do this just after the insert into MyTable1.

In cases where you want to insert multiple rows, the best way is to use an OUTPUT clause to get all the new identities into a working table.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server use SCOPE_IDENTITY() which gives the last generated identity value

```
UPDATE MyTable2
SET    MyTable1Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- how to get the value needed here
WHERE ...
```

Should you probably abort the whole thing if the first insert fails? Look into Try/Catch in SQL server, you'll find some good patterns there.